# Creating a child NIO.2 Path from a parent Path instance

Tags: java, path, nio

How do I create a `java.nio.file.Path` instance denoting a child path, if I already have an instance pointing to the parent directory on the same file system?

Currently, I'm using

```
final Path parent = Paths.get("usr", "local");
final Path child = Paths.get(parent.toString(), "bin");
```

-- but this doesn't look very elegant.

What I'm looking is some sort of a [`java.io.File(File parent, String child)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) constructor for *NIO.2*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write `child = parent.resolve("bin");`

[`resolve`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) can take Path or String as argument.

Comment: Here is also a nice [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#resolve) with examples.